# Calculate confidence interval for difference in means between 2 samples without individual sample values

Tags: confidence-interval

I have 2 samples, each containing 4 individual measurements, but I do not know what the individual measurements are, only what the group mean was for each sample. Is it possible to construct a confidence interval for the difference in means between the two groups or would I need to know the individual values (or at least the standard deviation among the samples) to do so?

Comment: Do you know anything besides the means?

Comment: I just know that the mean of the first sample is 11.8875 and the mean of the second sample is 11.275. Both contain 4 measurements each. My understanding is that I do not have enough information to calculate a confidence interval here but I was not sure if maybe there is some way to estimate it.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157582/what-can-we-say-about-population-mean-from-a-sample-size-of-1/157596#157596