# t-test using a sample less than 30

Tags: t-test, sample-size

When I do the two tailed t-test using a sample less than 30, can I use this result? This is because I do also still see the t-test table which has degrees of freedom far less than 30. How further small can the sample size be?

Comment: Is that 30 per group, or 30 total? If the latter, are the groups 15-15?

Comment: One case I have two groups 11-14, the other case I simply have one group to test with sample size less than 30.

Comment: The smallest possible sample sizes for a two-sample equal variance t-test is 1 and 2 (while many packages implement their tests in a way that precludes one of the samples having only one observation there's no good reason that they should do so --  R will do an equal variance t-test with 1 and 2 though, try: `t.test(1,c(3.5,3.2),var.equal=TRUE)`). Details are covered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44475/is-there-a-statistical-test-to-compare-two-samples-of-size-1-and-3).

Comment: If you're not fixed on it having to specifically be a t-test,  even smaller samples are possible. For example, one can adapt the discussion in whuber's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-perform-students-t-test-having-only-sample-size-sample-average-and-popu/1836#1836) (also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20300/how-can-i-get-the-ci-of-a-couple-of-numbers/20337#20337) and comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83186/can-you-do-statistics-with-4-data-points/83199#83199)) to a two sample test of means with $n_1=n_2=1$

Comment: It's not usually *advisable* to use such small $n$ but it's not an issue with the test "working" -- it still works as it should. But if your power is very low at anticipated effect sizes, then even if you reject you may have trouble convincing people it's not just a type I error. [Note also that it's not practical to use rank based tests down to sample sizes as low as the $t$ can be used for -- e.g. if you try to do a two-tailed Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney for n's of 1 & 2 the lowest achievable significance level is $\frac{_2}{^3}$].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-test are useful if the data is normally distributed and iid (@djima thank you). If the effect size is large you can use the t-test also if the sample size is small. So yes, you can use a t-test with a sample size which is smaller than 30.  The effect size can be calculated with [Cohen's D.](http://www.socscistatistics.com/effectsize/Default3.aspx). Under certain circumstances other measures such as the **Glass Delta** or the **Hedges G** are more useful.

> "The present simulation study showed that there is
>   no fundamental objection to using a regular t-test with
>   extremely small sample sizes. Even a sample size as
>   small as 2 did not pose problems. In most of the
>   simulated cases, the Type I error rate did not exceed
>   the nominal value of 5%. A paired t-test is also feasible
>   with extremely small sample sizes, particularly when the
>   within-pair correlation coefficient is high. (de Winter, 2013, p. 7)

J.C.F. de Winter (2013),
"Using the Student’s t-test with extremely small sample sizes,"
Practical Assessment, Research and Evaluation, 18:10, August, ISSN 1531-7714
http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=18&n=10

Comment: Normally distributed and IID! Correlated samples would inflate t-stats.

Comment: Thank you. So if the effect size from the Cohen's D test is 2.254386362
while my sample of two groups are 11-14, the t-test is ok, right?

Comment: @Eric yes you can do

Comment: @Ferdi: then if I have Cohen's D test value of -8.058891649 while each of my two group sample sizes are 9 and 6 respectively, do I conclude that I have enough sample size for t-test?

Comment: Yes. The absolute value of your number is really large. As your sample is very small you can have a look at it "by hand" and it should be evident.

Comment: @Ferdi: Hopefully this is the last question but I can use this test on the t-test which is simply to compare the mean difference with zero, can't I? For instance, if I have one group of data which I want to compare its mean value significance by comparing with zero, I can simply but the second group with mean=0, standard deviation=0 while the number of sample is the same as this non-zero group, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62910/discussion-between-ferdi-and-eric).